# Hadoop: Tracking the progress of a Local job

Tags: hadoop

I'm currently trying to do something similar to [Tracking Hadoop job status via web interface? (Exposing Hadoop to internal clients in the company)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616524/tracking-hadoop-job-status-via-web-interface-exposing-hadoop-to-internal-clien). The difference is that the job I'm targeting is a local job (this is running within a unit test). Here's what I'm doing (I'm interested in mapProgress):

```
        final String job = this.config.get("mapreduce.job.id");
        final JobClient client = new JobClient(this.config);
        final RunningJob running = client.getJob(JobID.forName(job));
        if (running == null) {
            Logger.warn(
                this, String.format("Job id does not exist: %s", job)
            );
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                String.format("No running job found: %s", job)
            );
        }
        while (running.mapProgress() < 1.0) {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        }
```

Now this doesn't actually work - I get an exception when I run it:

```
[←[0;33mWARN←[m] Thread-6 org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local204744704_0002
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No running job found: job_local204744704_0002
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:529)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No running job found: job_local204744704_0002
        at com.xockets.hadoop.XsInput.run(XsInput.java:150)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:376)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$ReduceTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:319)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I think JobClient is not designed to get information for local jobs. Is there a way to do something similar for a locally running job?